# OpenGL transparent framebuffer texture

Tags: opengl-es2, frame-buffer

I'm trying to implement atmospheric glow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14304193/1991295). It was a huge pain to get it done, since I'm new to FBO and OpenGL, but I managed to do something similar to what the OP wanted.

I followed his steps and now I'm rendering the resulting texture to my space environment. However, the texture is completely opaque and I only need the glow parts to be visible. How can I make the rest of the texture transparent? I'm using OpenGL ES 2 on Android.

Comment: Just as a suggestion have you looked into shader atmospheric scattering? It seems like it may be a bit easier http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter16.html

Comment: Yes I have a little bit, but I went for framebuffers & blur instead. I am interested in the answer to the question because I may need it in quite a few other situations.